# What's the actual value of eps in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

According to the MATLAB documentation, the value of `eps` should be `2^-52`.

"eps returns the distance from 1.0 to the next largest double-precision number, that is eps = 2^(-52)." (from http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html).

However, when I type `eps` in MATLAB's command window, I get `eps = 2.2204e-016`.

I'm confused. What *is* the actual value of `eps`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Err, on my machine Matlab gives `2^(-52) == 2.2204e-16`.  Am I missing something obvious in your question ?

Comment: You're right! That was stupid of me. I was thinking of 2*(10^(-52)), **not** 2^(-52). My bad, Sorry!